# How to retrieve value from array object.

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array object like this

```
DateTime Object(
[date] => 2016-03-15 01:59:40
[timezone_type] => 3
[timezone] => Asia/Singapore)
```

I want to get the value of date without h:i:s means i want the output like : 2016-03-15

How can i get the value in this format.

Comment: That's not an array, it's a `DateTime` object. Look at the [format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function to get the value in the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an array object - this is an DateTime Object. You could use the format method to get your desired output.

```
$ret = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```